# Uniform Random Number

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution

Two uniform random numbers are chosen one after the other. what is the probability of second number second random number greater than first number? I tried this way Please correct me if I am wrong.

$$X_1 \sim U(20,30)\\
X_2 \sim U(20,30)\\
P(X_2\geq X_1) = P(X_2-X_1\geq0) = 1-P(X_2-X_1 \geq 0) = 1- \left[X_3 - \frac{20}{10}\right].$$

I am stuck after this. I also tried solving this using conditional probability

$$P(X_2 > X_1 | X1) = \left(30-\frac{X_1}{10}\right)$$

Please help.

Thanks,
Ram

Comment: The answer depends on whether the uniform distribution is discrete or continuous.

Comment: @paw88789 The notation $U(20,30)$ suggests a continuous uniform distribution over the interval $[20,30]$...

Comment: @5xum: Well then, I agree with your answer.

Answer (score 2):

By symmetry, there can be no other probability other than $\frac12$. The probability of the two numbers being equal is $0$, and the probability of the first bein bigger is the same as the probability of the first being smaller.

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain himself? What in my answer is bad enough to earn a downvote?

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be iid random variables. Then $$P(X<Y)=P(Y<X)$$ Next to that we have: $$1=P(X<Y)+P(X=Y)+P(Y<X)$$ This together leads to: $$P(X<Y)=P(Y<X)=\frac{1}{2}(1-P(X=Y))$$ In your case $P(X=Y)=0$ so we end up with $$P(X<Y)=P(Y<X)=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Your argument holds provided $P(X=Y)=0$.

Comment: @paw88789 That is true for the last line: "in your case...we end up with..." The rest of it is true in general. In the case of the OP the distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is (absolutely) continuous. At least that's how I read it (uniformly over interval [20,30]).

Comment: Thanks Guys. Got it now. But lets say X1 = 29.5. P(X2 > 29.5) is definitely less than 50% right? Its this bias which dint let me to think 0.5 as the answer.